# How can I simplify and reduce execution time of my sql query with specific date format?

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I am using jdbcTemplate with following query and code

```
    String sql = select count(*) as count ,trunc(fin.fin_date) as dateAndTime from  (select * from rec where rec_status='RECEIVED' and fin_date>sysdate-8) fin group by trunc(fin.fin_date)

    try {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Chrt>() {
            @Override
            public Chrt mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Chrt receive = new Chrt();
                java.util.Date date =(rs.getDate("dateAndTime"));
                receive.setDate(date.toString());
                receive.setCount(rs.getInt("count"));
                return receive;
            }
        });
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
 }
```

It returns me date in a format like 2016-05-19 but I need the date like 19-MAY-16. Is it possible to get this format without increasing execution time?

How can I do this?

Comment: A Java `Date` has its' own internal representation (and it is not a `String`).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the [`trunc`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) function, you can use the [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) function. It will give you the date in the specified format:

```
String sql = select count(*) as count ,TO_CHAR(fin.fin_date, 'DD-MON-YY') as dateAndTime from  (select * from rec where rec_status='RECEIVED' and fin_date>sysdate-8) fin group by TO_CHAR(fin.fin_date, 'DD-MON-YY');
```

This will not impact performances significantly.

---

To increase performances, I suggest you to look at the query plan for the query. To see this plan, just execute :

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
select count(*) as count ,TO_CHAR(fin.fin_date, 'DD-MON-YY') as dateAndTime from  (select * from rec where rec_status='RECEIVED' and fin_date>sysdate-8) fin group by TO_CHAR(fin.fin_date, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

in any oracle sql client and [read the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm) to understand why it is too slow and how to improve performances. (a blind guess : put an index on fin_date)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use one query instead of two ?

```
select count(*) as count ,TO_CHAR(fin.fin_date, 'DD-MON-YY') as dateAndTime 
from rec 
where rec_status='RECEIVED' and fin_date>sysdate-8
group by TO_CHAR(fin.fin_date, 'DD-MON-YY');
```